# React Router & Express Conflicts

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router

I have paths that I want React Router to handle, and I also have an express API backend that I call from the React app to do some secure API calls.

`/#/` - want app served here
`/#/:id` - unique URLs for the app, i use the ID to call certain express endpoints from React.
`*` - all express REST endpoints

Express app.js:

```
app.use(middleware);
app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler, {
  log: console.log
}));
app.use('/api', [router_invokeBhApi]);
app.get('/#/*', function response(req, res) {
  res.write(middleware.fileSystem.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html')));
  res.end();
});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')))
```

My React router component:

```
export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/:id" component={ConsentForm} something="dope"/>
  </Route>
);
```

So here's what's happening:
- going to `localhost:8000` serves the app with the `HomePage` component
- going to `localhost:8000/#/` also serves the app with the `HomePage` component
- going to `localhost:8000/example` gives me `Cannot GET /example` which means express is working
- going to `localhost:8000/api` gives me a test JSON object which i send from express, which is correct.
- going to `localhost:8000/#/somehashcode` STILL gives me the `HomePage` component, when it SHOULD be giving me the `ConsentForm` component.

I inspected the Router component using React Dev tools:
- the RouterContext component has an object called `routes` with a `childRoutes` inside the `routes[0]`, and it has the path `/:id`. `routes[0]` also has a path `/` which tells me React Router loaded all the routes correctly??

So confused...

React file where I render the whole app:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import Routes from './shared/components/Routes';

import './shared/base.css';
import './shared/customInput.css';


const ROOT_ELEMENT = 'app';

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    {Routes}
  </Router>
), document.getElementById(ROOT_ELEMENT));
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information on the version of react-router you're using? According to their latest docs you have to use HashRouter, rather than just Route, from one of their packages. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter

Comment: @Michael 
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.28.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",

Comment: What's the render method of `App` look like?  Do you have a spot to correctly render the child components?

Comment: @gravityplanx I've updated the question with it

Comment: Still not including the info I was asking for though.  I'm asking specifically about the react component named `App`.  Does it's render method include a space for a child component?

Comment: @gravityplanx sorry sorry. yes it does. This is my `App.js` file:
`
import React from 'react';

export default React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
});
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out!

In the React `Router` component change the `:id` route to:

```
<Route path="/redirect/:id" component={ConsentForm} something="dope"/>
```

In Express, `app.js` change the React serve to:

```
app.get('/redirect/*', function response(req, res) {
  res.write(middleware.fileSystem.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html')));
  res.end();
});
```

Learnt 2 things from this:
- Using # in the route doesn't work. Not sure why.
- Explicitly state the route in the React side as well.

Quite weird, or maybe I'm going off some half-baked knowledge. Any resource to point me in the right direction would be so awesome.

Pretty sure someone else is going to run into this as they use Express and React together.

Answer (score 0):

Found your problem.

You're using `BrowserHistory` in your configuration.  This option (the recommended one at present) does not use a hash in the uri, but instead directly integrates with the browser.

Try hitting your app at `localhost:8000/somehashcode` and see what you get.

Comment: `http://localhost:8000/somehashcode` gives me 'Cannot GET /somehashcode' meaning express is handling that route right?

Comment: Sounds like it, which means you have a conflict between your routing tools.  To solve this you should either 1;  set up a wildcard route in express so that any unmatched `get` request renders your react application or 2; swap out react-router's `BrowserHistory` for it's `HashHistory`, which would use the uri's in your original question.

Comment: I just want a way for certain URLs to be handled by express and certain by React. Is there a way for them to not conflict like that? I don't even understand why they are conflicting in the first place when I clearly specify only URLs starting with `/#/*` to be handled by React. I'll test it with HashHistory, give me a few minutes

Comment: Using `HashHistory` sort of works (able to access the Form component and Home component using the URLs, still unable to access the express routes though.

Comment: I think your issue stems from misunderstanding what hash params are.  Hash params are similar to normal params (e.g. `localhost:8000/?hasparam=somehashcode`) with the exception of the fact that *they are not passed to the server).  Your express configuration specifying `app.get('/#/*'...`, therefore, doesn't really make sense.

Comment: ohh I didn't know that.... I need to read into hash history. So how would I still have express REST endpoints with a hashHistory instead?