# Mix React Router For SPA and Express router for OAuth(API call)

Tags: reactjs, express, oauth, react-router

I tried to do a React app with React Router and github oauth.

But Github Oauth doesn't support cors api call and not secure to store secret key in front end.

So I plan to host my react app in Express and use express to do the backend github oauth call.

Then, I found out that when Express Router mix with React-Router, the Express Router will not work, probably blocked by React-Router.

Express code is here:

```
const express = require('express')
const randomstring = require('randomstring');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express()

let state = '';

app.get('/authorize', function (req, res) {
  state = randomstring.generate();
  res.redirect('http://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?' + 'client_id=3ba48xxxx6d6d0&state=' + state);
})

app.get('/auth-callback', function (req, res) {
  if (state === req.params.state) {
    axios.post('https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token', {
      client_id: '3ba48xxxx6d6d',
      client_secret: 'xxxx',
      code: req.params.code
    }).then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  };
});

app.use(express.static('build'))

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./build/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

This is probably related to this one [React Router & Express Conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789775/react-router-express-conflicts) which I think it's the same idea.

So when I link my login button to '/authorize', it was not intercepted by express.

The login button

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import authService from '../GithubAuth/AuthService.js';

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      redirectToReferrer: false
    };
  }
  state = {
    redirectToReferrer: false
  }

  login = () => {
    authService.authenticate(() => {
      this.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true })
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: '/' } }
    const { redirectToReferrer } = this.state

    if (redirectToReferrer) {
      return (
        <Redirect to={from} />
      )
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <p>You must log in to view the page at {from.pathname}</p>
        <button onClick={this.login}>Log in</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Login;
```

authenService.js

```
import * as Cookies from "js-cookie";

export default {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate(cb) {
    const githubToken = Cookies.get('github_token');
    if (githubToken) {
      this.isAuthenticated = true
    } else {
      global.location.href = '/authorize';
    }
    setTimeout(cb, 100) // fake async
  },
  signout(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = false
    setTimeout(cb, 100)
  }
}
```

Can some expert explain why and show me how to it correctly?

Comment: Can you post the URL of the page from where you call /authorize?

Comment: @VivekN posted.

Comment: Think I have a similar problem, did you ever manage to fix it?